# Line Contact Key Updates in Group Connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contact, data-views, subscriber-key

our requirement is we need to send a message when active in LINE account and should not send when not active using journey builder.

In the journey, before we send LINE message we check the LINE status in Group Connect subscription data view table matched with the contact key and in our entry source data extension we use the same contact key relates with subscriber key.
We found when member who already in Journey, blocks the LINE account, the LINE ID record got removed in GroupConnect and again synched back with new Contact key if they unblock LINE account.

In the above scenario, how can we check the line status with the old contact key when the user unblocking the LINE account in journey builder while in the middle of the journey?
Could you please help on the above
Thanks
Venkat

Comment: What would you do in the Journey if the ContactKey used by the Journey is no longer present in GroupConnect? Would you send and email or SMS? You wouldn't be able to send a LINE message.

Comment: Will send EMAIL

Comment: Why not use a decision split... "Contact Data > GroupConnect Line Addresses > Contact Key IS NOT NULL"?

Comment: our scenario is if the user is not there in group connect we will send email using decision split but when user activated again they will come back to group connect with different contact key..in that case how would we send LINE message to the user, if the user in the middle of the journey?